# Object not passing to controller from factory method

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I am trying to create a factory that will query Firebase and iterate through the results to pass the logged in user's profile object to the controller.

This is the factory:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')

.factory('Users', ['$firebaseObject', 'Auth', function($firebaseObject, Auth) {
    var usersRef = new Firebase('https://ld-tutor.firebaseio.com/users/');
    var users = $firebaseObject(usersRef);

    var authData = Auth.$getAuth();

    var Users = {
        getProfile: function(){
            var uid = authData.uid;
            users.$loaded().then(function(){
                angular.forEach(users, function(user){
                    if(user.uid == uid){
                        return user;
                    }
                });
            });
        },
    };

    return Users;
}]);
```

This is the controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.content', ['ui.router'])

.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', 'Users', function($scope, Users) {

    $scope.profile = Users.getProfile();

}]);
```

The problem is that `$scope.profile` ends up being undefined. If I go to the factory and change `return user;` to `console.log(user);` then I am able to see the correct object display in the debugging area. However, when I go to the controller and replace `$scope.profile = Users.getProfile();` with `$scope.profile = console.log(Users.getProfile());` it shows undefined. After a lot of research I have not been able to figure this out. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything. Your promise _resolves_ to something at some point down the road, but you don't return the promise so your controller isn't informed when that happens.

Comment: I thought the return inside the if statement would do this

Comment: Yes, it's easy to think that, but that statement doesn't execute until the data comes back.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, return the promise from your factory and use `.then(function(user){ ... }` in your controller.

The return before `users.$loaded()` in the code below will immediately return the promise and once it resolves the `then` callback will be exectued.

Updated code (not tested but it should work like this):

factory

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')

.factory('Users', ['$firebaseObject', 'Auth', function($firebaseObject, Auth) {
    var usersRef = new Firebase('https://ld-tutor.firebaseio.com/users/');
    var users = $firebaseObject(usersRef);

    var authData = Auth.$getAuth();

    var Users = {
        getProfile: function(){
            var uid = authData.uid;
            return users.$loaded().then(function(){
            angular.forEach(users, function(user){
                if(user.uid == uid){
                    return user;
                }
            });
        });
    },
};

return Users;
}]);
```

controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.content', ['ui.router'])
.controller('DashCtrl', ['$scope', 'Users', function($scope, Users) {

    //$scope.profile = Users.getProfile();
    Users.getProfile().then(function(user) {
        $scope.profile = user;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in the console pane afterwards.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. But it should work. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/uvrsxgLm/) and replace the firebase ref with your url for testing. I've just added a public ref to have some dummy data.